# I want to get this href (this URL), but I am not able to get it using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, casperjs

The `href` attribute is present here:

[image: the href attribute is present here]

I'm trying to get this as a URL `"CompanyDetails.aspx?ISIN=EGS3G191C017"` from the image using CasperJS, but I am unable to get it.

I have used these approaches but was unsuccessful:

**Attempt #1:**

```
var links = self.casper.getElementAttribute('//* 
[@id="ctl00_C_S_RadGrid2_ctl00_ctl05_divContainer"]/a[1]', 'href');

Error: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 
'__utils__.findOne(selector).getAttribute')
```

**Attempt #2:**

```
var links = self.casper.getElementsAttribute(x('//* 
[@id="ctl00_C_S_RadGrid2_ctl00_ctl05_divContainer"]/a[1]'), 'href');
```

Here, I didn't get an error, but `var links` was containing a blank space only.

Answer (score 0):

```
const link = document
            .getElementById('ctl00_C_S_RadGrid2_ctl00_ctl05_divContainer')
            .firstElementChild
            .getAttribute('href');
```

Comment: I got this error on using this : TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('ctl00_C_S_RadGrid2_ctl00_ctl05_divContainer').firstElementChild')

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using javascript directly with casper's method evaluate which will bring you to browser context

```
var link = casper.evaluate(function() {
    return document.querySelector('ctl00_C_S_RadGrid2_ctl00_ctl05_divContainer a').href;
})
```

Hope that helps